# Autofilling a spreadsheet column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a function that will copy the last value in a column down until it meets the last value of another column. Here is what the input will look like:

[image]

I want the script to find "Peach" in Column F (the last value in the column) and copy it down until it hits the last cell in column G. New values will be added every day, which is why I can't use absolute references. This is what I want the output to look like:

[image]

And here is my current (non-functioning) code:

```
function CopyDown(){
   //Total length of column G
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(WORKSHEETID);
   var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Approval");
   var endRow = spreadsheet.getRange("G:G").getLastRow()

   //Getting last data in column F
   var currentRow = spreadsheet.getRange("F:F").getLastRow()
   var oneRowCopy = sheet.getRange(currentRow,6);

   //Copying down
   var targetRows = sheet.getRange(currentRow+1,6,endRow, 1);
   oneRowCopy.copyTo(targetRows);

 };
```

Can anyone explain how to get this code to function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make Column F and G same height by filling in empty cells in F with last row in F.

```
function CopyDown(){
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");//Modified sheet name
  const glr=getColumnHeight(7,sh,ss);//last row in G
  const flr=getColumnHeight(6,sh,ss);//last row in F
  const flv=sh.getRange(flr,6).getValue();//last value in F
  const fbrg=sh.getRange(flr+1,6,glr-flr,1);//empty range in F
  const bA=fbrg.getValues();//empty values in F
  bA.forEach(function(r){r[0]=flv});//fill empty values with f last value
  fbrg.setValues(bA);//copy values all at one time
}
```

Helper function:

```
function getColumnHeight(col,sh,ss){
  var ss=ss||SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=sh||ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col=col||sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  const rcA=sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues().reverse()
  let s=0;
  for(let i=0;i<rcA.length;i++) {
    if(rcA[i][0].toString().length==0) {
      s++;
    }else{
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length-s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the **SpreadSheetApp** class/variable so I can understand how does it work?

How to find an exact value:

```
const list = ["one", "two", "three"];
const index = list.indexOf("two"); //1, because arrays start with the index of 0
```

How to find if it includes:

```
const list = ["apple", "banana", "pear"];
const index = list.indexOf(list.find(e => e.includes("app"))); //0, because "apple" includes "app"
```

In your case, you need to find the index. So make a list with the elements of column F.
Search for it with one of the methods I showed above. Then, do a for loop something like this:

```
for (var i = index; i < /*column G length*/; i++) {
columnG[i].text = "Peach"; //I don't really know how it really works, sorry. Make it how you would change the text.
}
```